# Primary Goes down and Secondary now Primary - How to write to new Primary?

Tags: c#, python, mongodb, pymongo

If I have a MongoDB Replica set where I have 3 nodes (Primary, Secondary, Arbiter) and the Primary node goes down and now Secondary assumes Primary how do you dynamically handle that change in your clients so that they will now write to Primary?

I experienced this in a dev environmetn and started thinking about the best approach to handle this.  This is not a shard cluster, just a standalone replica set.

Do you check something in the connection like "IsPrimary" so that if it isn't you change where you write?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set up the connections the drivers should be smart enough to sort out which node the data should be sent to.

[For the C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Connectionstrings):

> To connect to a replica set specify the seed list by providing
>   multiple hostnames (and port numbers if required) separated by commas.
>   For example:
>
> `mongodb://server1,server2:27017,server2:27018`

[For the Python driver](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/replica_set.html):

> A connection to a replica set can be made using the normal
>   Connection() constructor, specifying one or more members of the set.
>   For example, any of the following will create a connection to the set
>   we just created:

```
Connection("morton.local", replicaset='foo')
Connection([u'morton.local:27019', 'morton.local:27017', u'morton.local:27018'])
Connection("morton.local:27018", replicaset='foo')
Connection([u'morton.local:27019', u'morton.local:27017', 'morton.local:27018'])
Connection("morton.local", 27019, replicaset='foo')
Connection(['morton.local:27019', u'morton.local:27017', u'morton.local:27018'])
Connection(["morton.local:27018", "morton.local:27019"])
Connection(['morton.local:27019', u'morton.local:27017', 'morton.local:27018'])
Connection("mongodb://morton.local:27017,morton.local:27018,morton.local:27019")
Connection(['morton.local:27019', 'morton.local:27017', 'morton.local:27018'])
```

> The nodes passed to Connection() are called the seeds. If only one
>   host is specified the replicaset parameter must be used to indicate
>   this isn’t a connection to a single node. As long as at least one of
>   the seeds is online, the driver will be able to “discover” all of the
>   nodes in the set and make a connection to the current primary.

Comment: Thanks Wilfred...that is exactly what I found as well

Answer (score 2):

So far what I am finding leads me to believe that it is the driver that will actually direct this properly.  I think my C# driver setting is correct, but how I am connecting via my Python client (PyMongo) is not.  I should be using something like pymongo.ReplicaSetConnection

Shown [Here](http://emptysquare.net/blog/save-the-monkey-reliably-writing-to-mongodb/).

I will keep digging, but wanted to share what I have found so far.

**EDIT:**

C# - Driver was properly handling connection so good there

Python: Needed to modify my connection as I stated above so that it would route the writes to the new Primary

Python (pymongo) Code:

```
from pymongo.replica_set_connection import ReplicaSetConnection

MongoConnection = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017',replicaSet='myReplSet')
```

--S

Comment: You are right, if you have set up the connection (depending on the driver) as a replica set, or hosts vs. host in ruby etc. then the driver will handle the failover and reconnect you to the new master once the election is done (you will see it doing isMaster or similar to figure it out)